# Как создать свой вертексный шейдер?

Tags: delphi, opengl

Как реализовать в openGL функционал по типу загрузки в шейдер массива вершин и матрицы перехода и выдать по итогу массив преобразованных вершин. Я пишу свой велосипед по визуализации 3D объектов (для курсовой), но понял что на CPU расcчитывать преобразования всех вершин очень долго, хочу выполнять данные действия на видеокарте, но плохо в этом разбираюсь. Очень приветствуются вставки примеров кода и ссылки на статьи с информацией по этому поводу

Comment: В двух словах - OpenGL принимает вершины и выдает картинку. У него нельзя "просто так" забрать преобразованные вершины. Для математики, возможно вам больше подойдет OpenCL. Поищите уроки/туториалы - там все будет разжевано.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как код на GLSL использовать в delphi](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1501005/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%bd%d0%b0-glsl-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2-delphi)

Comment: Не нужно задавать несколько похожих вопросов, вы можете отредактировать предыдущий.

Comment: @Kromster спасибо, информация про OpenCl мне очень помогла, но не могли бы вы подсказать где есть информация про использования OpenCl в delphi

Comment: К сожалению сам OpenCL не занимался и туториалов по ней в Делфи не встречал

Comment: есть туториалы по использованию opencv в делфи, а в opencv, чтобы вычисления пошли через GPU достаточно заменить тип данных cv::Mat на cv::UMat